# Python dictionary, adding a new value to key if present multiple times in list

Tags: python, dictionary

Im trying to split a string of letters into a dictionary which automatically adds the value +1 for every letter present more than once.

The only problem is that my code adds the value +1 for every key...For example if i input: "aasf" the dict will be: a:2, s:2, f:2... Whats wrong??

```
word = raw_input("Write letters: ")
chars = {}

for c in word:
    chars[c] = c.count(c)
    if c in chars:
        chars[c] += 1
print chars
```

Comment: `c.count(c)` will always be 1 -- I think you mean `word.count(c)`. Also, it's not clear what you want the output values to be -- 2, 1, 1 or 3, 2, 2? Or something else?

Comment: `for c in word: chars[c] = chars.get(c, 0) + 1` dict.get with 2nd argument uses it if key is absent.

Comment: For your sample input of 'aasf' what should the output be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use either

```
chars[c] = words.count(c)
```

OR

```
chars[c] += 1
```

but not both.

Comment: Please format code. Also, I think his homework problem might be to add an extra +1 for each one that appears more than once, but it's not clear.

Answer (score 3):

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('count letters in this sentence')
Counter({'e': 5, 't': 5, ' ': 4, 'n': 4, 's': 3, 'c': 2, 'i': 2, 'h': 1, 'l': 1, 'o': 1, 'r': 1, 'u': 1})
>>>
```